# View entire page source

Tags: html, css, frames

Recently was asked to make changes to a website `www.studentscounseling.org`. I went to the address and clicked clicked `view page source`. Despite the entire site easily being at least 1,000 lines of code, the browser output this code block.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Students Counseling | Home </title>
<META name="description" content="Get Answers to Questions on Student Debt. The Federal programs May Help You Drastically Lower Your Student Loan Payment--Learn More!"><META name="keywords" content="Students Counseling, Student loan forgiveness, financial aid, student loan payment, obamam forgiveness program, college loans, student loans">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="http://studentcounseling.org" frameborder="0" />
<frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 01 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

I copied the code and tested it in a local server environment and it worked; it produced all the elements displayed on the webpage. The only thing is I need to edit those elements directly and the code above doesn't show all the code for some reason. My guess is that the site uses frames. When I click in a designated frame area, I get the option to `View Frame Source`. I'd like to copy the ENTIRE FILE at once to make edits to it. Is there a way to do this or will I have to go frame by frame, line by line hoping I end up copying all the real code used for the site's production?

***Update: Thanks to you all, it turns out the code for `studentscounseling.org` is hosted at `studentcounseling.org`. Now the only thing is the fact that there is no CSS on that page. Thanks for the help. I will try the fire bug option and also simply requesting the whole file from the admin. ***

I gotsta get paid

Comment: try view-source:http://studentcounseling.org/

Comment: If you've been tasked with updating the web site, aren't they giving you access to the source code anyway? I'm not understanding why you have to use View Source at all.

Comment: @BSMP you're right, I just texted him to just try to give me the file. (The old site runner was trying to keep the code to himself or something so he's going to have to do some sweet talking to get it back)

Comment: @newday view-source just outputs the above code block without the actual frame elements

Comment: Oh dear, this isn't a thing where they didn't pay the last person to work on this, is it? Because that implies that they won't pay you either.

Comment: Did you actually look at the source you posted? You say, "My guess is that the site uses frames." The source you posted contains two `<frame>` tags, so yes, it does. It also tells you where the bulk of the page's content comes from, in the line `<frame src="http://studentcounseling.org" frameborder="0" />`. This is exactly what [Digital Chris's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38926458/2057919) points out. Please note that we expect you to put in at least some minimal effort before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your browser toolkit,or firebug for mozilla, you can actually do this.

Load the page, load your tool, go to source/HTML section, and copy the code from there : select it and use "copy innerHTML".

Here is the result :

```
<head>
<title>Students Counseling | Home</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Students Counseling">

<!--[if !IE]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"12988ea13f78fe3e7cd298b37b4415bf",petok:"60f90cb3eaaf05e9ae6190dded944f14f3d6d33d-1471035959-86400",zone:"studentcounseling.org",rocket:"a",apps:0,sha2test:0}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=0489c402f5/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=0489c402f5/cloudflare.min.js"></script><style type="text/css">.cf-hidden { display: none; } .cf-invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style><script data-module="cloudflare/rocket" id="cfjs_block_8c93f46e8c" onload="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_8c93f46e8c_load()" onerror="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_8c93f46e8c_error()" onreadystatechange="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_8c93f46e8c_readystatechange()" type="text/javascript" src="http://studentcounseling.org/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/cloudflare/rocket.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!--[endif]-->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico">
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

<script data-rocketoptimized="true" data-rocketsrc="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>


<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="js/move-top.js"></script>
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="js/easing.js"></script>
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
            });
        });
</script>


<script data-rocketoptimized="true" data-rocketsrc="js/menu_jquery.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>

<style class="firebugResetStyles" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">/* See license.txt for terms of usage */
/** reset styling **/
.firebugResetStyles {
    z-index: 2147483646 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    display: block !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    min-width: 0 !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    max-height: none !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent none !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
style.firebugResetStyles {
    display: none !important;
}

.firebugBlockBackgroundColor {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.firebugResetStyles:before, .firebugResetStyles:after {
    content: "" !important;
}
/**actual styling to be modified by firebug theme**/
.firebugCanvas {
    display: none !important;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
.firebugLayoutBox {
    width: auto !important;
    position: static !important;
}

.firebugLayoutBoxOffset {
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLine {
    opacity: 0.4 !important;
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineLeft, .firebugLayoutLineRight {
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineTop, .firebugLayoutLineBottom {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 1px !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineTop {
    margin-top: -1px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineRight {
    border-right: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineBottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}

.firebugLayoutLineLeft {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
.firebugLayoutBoxParent {
    border-top: 0 none !important;
    border-right: 1px dashed #E00 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E00 !important;
    border-left: 0 none !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

.firebugRuler{
    position: absolute !important;
}

.firebugRulerH {
    top: -15px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    background: url("data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%13%88%00%00%00%0E%08%02%00%00%00L%25a%0A%00%00%00%04gAMA%00%00%D6%D8%D4OX2%00%00%00%19tEXtSoftware%00Adobe%20ImageReadyq%C9e%3C%00%00%04%F8IDATx%DA%EC%DD%D1n%E2%3A%00E%D1%80%F8%FF%EF%E2%AF2%95%D0D4%0E%C1%14%B0%8Fa-%E9%3E%CC%9C%87n%B9%81%A6W0%1C%A6i%9A%E7y%0As8%1CT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AATE9%FE%FCw%3E%9F%AF%2B%2F%BA%97%FDT%1D~K(%5C%9D%D5%EA%1B%5C%86%B5%A9%BDU%B5y%80%ED%AB*%03%FAV9%AB%E1%CEj%E7%82%EF%FB%18%BC%AEJ8%AB%FA'%D2%BEU9%D7U%ECc0%E1%A2r%5DynwVi%CFW%7F%BB%17%7Dy%EACU%CD%0E%F0%FA%3BX%FEbV%FEM%9B%2B%AD%BE%AA%E5%95v%AB%AA%E3E5%DCu%15rV9%07%B5%7F%B5w%FCm%BA%BE%AA%FBY%3D%14%F0%EE%C7%60%0EU%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5JU%88%D3%F5%1F%AE%DF%3B%1B%F2%3E%DAUCNa%F92%D02%AC%7Dm%F9%3A%D4%F2%8B6%AE*%BF%5C%C2Ym~9g5%D0Y%95%17%7C%C8c%B0%7C%18%26%9CU%CD%13i%F7%AA%90%B3Z%7D%95%B4%C7%60%E6E%B5%BC%05%B4%FBY%95U%9E%DB%FD%1C%FC%E0%9F%83%7F%BE%17%7DkjMU%E3%03%AC%7CWj%DF%83%9An%BCG%AE%F1%95%96yQ%0Dq%5Dy%00%3Et%B5'%FC6%5DS%95pV%95%01%81%FF'%07%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%F8x%C7%F0%BE%9COp%5D%C9%7C%AD%E7%E6%EBV%FB%1E%E0(%07%E5%AC%C6%3A%ABi%9C%8F%C6%0E9%AB%C0'%D2%8E%9F%F99%D0E%B5%99%14%F5%0D%CD%7F%24%C6%DEH%B8%E9rV%DFs%DB%D0%F7%00k%FE%1D%84%84%83J%B8%E3%BA%FB%EF%20%84%1C%D7%AD%B0%8E%D7U%C8Y%05%1E%D4t%EF%AD%95Q%BF8w%BF%E9%0A%BF%EB%03%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%B8vJ%8E%BB%F5%B1u%8Cx%80%E1o%5E%CA9%AB%CB%CB%8E%03%DF%1D%B7T%25%9C%D5(%EFJM8%AB%CC'%D2%B2*%A4s%E7c6%FB%3E%FA%A2%1E%80~%0E%3E%DA%10x%5D%95Uig%15u%15%ED%7C%14%B6%87%A1%3B%FCo8%A8%D8o%D3%ADO%01%EDx%83%1A~%1B%9FpP%A3%DC%C6'%9C%95gK%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%20%D9%C9%11%D0%C0%40%AF%3F%EE%EE%92%94%D6%16X%B5%BCMH%15%2F%BF%D4%A7%C87%F1%8E%F2%81%AE%AAvzr%DA2%ABV%17%7C%E63%83%E7I%DC%C6%0Bs%1B%EF6%1E%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%80cr%9CW%FF%7F%C6%01%0E%F1%CE%A5%84%B3%CA%BC%E0%CB%AA%84%CE%F9%BF)%EC%13%08WU%AE%AB%B1%AE%2BO%EC%8E%CBYe%FE%8CN%ABr%5Dy%60~%CFA%0D%F4%AE%D4%BE%C75%CA%EDVB%EA(%B7%F1%09g%E5%D9%12%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00H%F6%EB%13S%E7y%5E%5E%FB%98%F0%22%D1%B2'%A7%F0%92%B1%BC%24z3%AC%7Dm%60%D5%92%B4%7CEUO%5E%F0%AA*%3BU%B9%AE%3E%A0j%94%07%A0%C7%A0%AB%FD%B5%3F%A0%F7%03T%3Dy%D7%F7%D6%D4%C0%AAU%D2%E6%DFt%3F%A8%CC%AA%F2%86%B9%D7%F5%1F%18%E6%01%F8%CC%D5%9E%F0%F3z%88%AA%90%EF%20%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%C0%A6%D3%EA%CFi%AFb%2C%7BB%0A%2B%C3%1A%D7%06V%D5%07%A8r%5D%3D%D9%A6%CAu%F5%25%CF%A2%99%97zNX%60%95%AB%5DUZ%D5%FBR%03%AB%1C%D4k%9F%3F%BB%5C%FF%81a%AE%AB'%7F%F3%EA%FE%F3z%94%AA%D8%DF%5B%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%8E%FB%F3%F2%B1%1B%8DWU%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*UiU%C7%BBe%E7%F3%B9%CB%AAJ%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5*%AAj%FD%C6%D4%5Eo%90%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5%86%AF%1B%9F%98%DA%EBm%BBV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%AD%D6%E4%F58%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%40%85%7F%02%0C%008%C2%D0H%16j%8FX%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82") repeat-x !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #BBBBBB !important;
    border-right: 1px dashed #BBBBBB !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}

.firebugRulerV {
    top: 0 !important;
    left: -15px !important;
    width: 14px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    background: url("data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%0E%00%00%13%88%08%02%00%00%00%0E%F5%CB%10%00%00%00%04gAMA%00%00%D6%D8%D4OX2%00%00%00%19tEXtSoftware%00Adobe%20ImageReadyq%C9e%3C%00%00%06~IDATx%DA%EC%DD%D1v%A20%14%40Qt%F1%FF%FF%E4%97%D9%07%3BT%19%92%DC%40(%90%EEy%9A5%CB%B6%E8%F6%9Ac%A4%CC0%84%FF%DC%9E%CF%E7%E3%F1%88%DE4%F8%5D%C7%9F%2F%BA%DD%5E%7FI%7D%F18%DDn%BA%C5%FB%DF%97%BFk%F2%10%FF%FD%B4%F2M%A7%FB%FD%FD%B3%22%07p%8F%3F%AE%E3%F4S%8A%8F%40%EEq%9D%BE8D%F0%0EY%A1Uq%B7%EA%1F%81%88V%E8X%3F%B4%CEy%B7h%D1%A2E%EBohU%FC%D9%AF2fO%8BBeD%BE%F7X%0C%97%A4%D6b7%2Ck%A5%12%E3%9B%60v%B7r%C7%1AI%8C%BD%2B%23r%00c0%B2v%9B%AD%CA%26%0C%1Ek%05A%FD%93%D0%2B%A1u%8B%16-%95q%5Ce%DCSO%8E%E4M%23%8B%F7%C2%FE%40%BB%BD%8C%FC%8A%B5V%EBu%40%F9%3B%A72%FA%AE%8C%D4%01%CC%B5%DA%13%9CB%AB%E2I%18%24%B0n%A9%0CZ*Ce%9C%A22%8E%D8NJ%1E%EB%FF%8F%AE%CAP%19*%C3%BAEKe%AC%D1%AAX%8C*%DEH%8F%C5W%A1e%AD%D4%B7%5C%5B%19%C5%DB%0D%EF%9F%19%1D%7B%5E%86%BD%0C%95%A12%AC%5B*%83%96%CAP%19%F62T%86%CAP%19*%83%96%CA%B8Xe%BC%FE)T%19%A1%17xg%7F%DA%CBP%19*%C3%BA%A52T%86%CAP%19%F62T%86%CA%B0n%A9%0CZ%1DV%C6%3D%F3%FCH%DE%B4%B8~%7F%5CZc%F1%D6%1F%AF%84%F9%0F6%E6%EBVt9%0E~%BEr%AF%23%B0%97%A12T%86%CAP%19%B4T%86%CA%B8Re%D8%CBP%19*%C3%BA%A52huX%19%AE%CA%E5%BC%0C%7B%19*CeX%B7h%A9%0C%95%E1%BC%0C%7B%19*CeX%B7T%06%AD%CB%5E%95%2B%BF.%8F%C5%97%D5%E4%7B%EE%82%D6%FB%CF-%9C%FD%B9%CF%3By%7B%19%F62T%86%CA%B0n%D1R%19*%A3%D3%CA%B0%97%A12T%86uKe%D0%EA%B02*%3F1%99%5DB%2B%A4%B5%F8%3A%7C%BA%2B%8Co%7D%5C%EDe%A8%0C%95a%DDR%19%B4T%C66%82fA%B2%ED%DA%9FC%FC%17GZ%06%C9%E1%B3%E5%2C%1A%9FoiB%EB%96%CA%A0%D5qe4%7B%7D%FD%85%F7%5B%ED_%E0s%07%F0k%951%ECr%0D%B5C%D7-g%D1%A8%0C%EB%96%CA%A0%A52T%C6)*%C3%5E%86%CAP%19%D6-%95A%EB*%95q%F8%BB%E3%F9%AB%F6%E21%ACZ%B7%22%B7%9B%3F%02%85%CB%A2%5B%B7%BA%5E%B7%9C%97%E1%BC%0C%EB%16-%95%A12z%AC%0C%BFc%A22T%86uKe%D0%EA%B02V%DD%AD%8A%2B%8CWhe%5E%AF%CF%F5%3B%26%CE%CBh%5C%19%CE%CB%B0%F3%A4%095%A1%CAP%19*Ce%A8%0C%3BO*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12%3A%AD%8C%0A%82%7B%F0v%1F%2FD%A9%5B%9F%EE%EA%26%AF%03%CA%DF9%7B%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12T%86%CA%B8Ze%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%D1ae%EC%F7%89I%E1%B4%D7M%D7P%8BjU%5C%BB%3E%F2%20%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12T%C6%D5*%C3%5E%86%CAP%19*Ce%B4O%07%7B%F0W%7Bw%1C%7C%1A%8C%B3%3B%D1%EE%AA%5C%D6-%EBV%83%80%5E%D0%CA%10%5CU%2BD%E07YU%86%CAP%19*%E3%9A%95%91%D9%A0%C8%AD%5B%EDv%9E%82%FFKOee%E4%8FUe%A8%0C%95%A12T%C6%1F%A9%8C%C8%3D%5B%A5%15%FD%14%22r%E7B%9F%17l%F8%BF%ED%EAf%2B%7F%CF%ECe%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%E1%93~%7B%19%F62T%86%CAP%19*Ce%A8%0C%E7%13%DA%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0C%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0C%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4%AE%A4%F5%25%C0%00%DE%BF%5C'%0F%DA%B8q%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82") repeat-y !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #BBBBBB !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #BBBBBB !important;
}

.overflowRulerX > .firebugRulerV {
    left: 0 !important;
}

.overflowRulerY > .firebugRulerH {
    top: 0 !important;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
.fbProxyElement {
    position: fixed !important;
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
</style></head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="header-left">
<ul>
<li><a href="account.html">ACCOUNT</a></li>
<li class="login">
<div id="loginContainer"><a id="loginButton"><span>LOGIN</span></a>
<div id="loginBox">
<form id="loginForm">
<fieldset id="body">
<fieldset>
<label for="email">Email Address</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password">
</fieldset>
<input id="login" value="Sign in" type="submit">
<label for="checkbox"><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <i>Remember me</i></label>
</fieldset>
<span><a href="account.html">Forgot your password?</a></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;" class="logo wow fadeInDown animated">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="images/logo4.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="top-nav">
<span class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""></span>
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="codes.html">Repayment Estimator</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript">                   
                            $("span.menu").click(function(){
                                $(".top-nav ul").slideToggle("slow" , function(){
                                });
                            });
                </script>

</div>
<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;" class="search-box wow fadeIn animated">
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
<form>
<input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="search term..." name="search" id="search" type="search">
<input class="sb-search-submit" value="" type="submit">
<span class="sb-icon-search"> </span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;" class="headerphone wow zoomIn animated">
<a href="tel:1-888-668-8109"><h2 style="margin-top:-60px;">CALL NOW (888) 668-8109</h2></a>
<a href="tel:1-888-668-8109"><h2 style="float:right; margin-top:-90px;">OPEN M-F 9AM-6PM PST</h2></a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>

<script data-rocketoptimized="true" data-rocketsrc="js/classie.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" data-rocketsrc="js/uisearch.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript">
                    new UISearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) );
                </script>

</div>
</div>


<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;" class="banner wow fadeIn animated">

<script data-rocketoptimized="true" data-rocketsrc="js/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketoptimized="true" type="text/rocketscript">
            // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
                $(function () {
                // Slideshow 3
                    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
                    auto: true,
                    pager:true,
                    nav:true,
                    speed: 500,
                    namespace: "callbacks",
                    before: function () {
                    $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
                    },
                    after: function () {
                        $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
                    }
                }); 
            });
        </script>

<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;" id="rslides" class="callbacks_container wow fadeIn animated">
<ul class="rslides callbacks callbacks1" id="slider3">
<li class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;" id="callbacks1_s0">
<div class="banner1">
<div id="view_header1" class="contents col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5 col-md-4">
<h1 style="font-weight:900; color:#fff; text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);">So You've Graduated, what now? <br> Whether you left college with a degree or not you're still on the hook for Students payments.</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;" id="callbacks1_s1">
<div class="banner1 banner2">
<div id="view_header2" class="contents col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
<h1 style="font-weight:900; color:#000; text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);">We can help! <br> Doesn't matter if you've been out of school for 12 weeks, 12 months or 12 years, There's a plan for you.</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="callbacks1_on" style="display: block; float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;" id="callbacks1_s2">
<div class="banner1 banner3">
<div id="view_header3" class="contents col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5 col-md-4">
<h1 style="font-weight:900; color:#fff; text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);">Find out how we can make a difference for you &amp; <span class="highlight" style="color:#000;">Spread the Word!</span></h1>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul><a href="#" class="callbacks_nav callbacks1_nav prev">Previous</a><a href="#" class="callbacks_nav callbacks1_nav next">Next</a><ul class="callbacks_tabs callbacks1_tabs"><li class="callbacks1_s1"><a href="#" class="callbacks1_s1">1</a></li><li class="callbacks1_s2"><a href="#" class="callbacks1_s2">2</a></li><li class="callbacks1_s3 callbacks_here"><a href="#" class="callbacks1_s3">3</a></li></ul>
<div style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" id="view_video" class="contents col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4 wow fadeInUp animated">
<div class="signup">
<div class="signup-header"><br>
<h3 class="form-title">GET A CONFIDENTIAL Students ASSESSMENT</h3><span><p>Reserve your place now before these programs close!</p></span><br>
<form class="form-header" action="http://Studentsloancounseling.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post" role="form" method="POST" id="#">
<input name="u" value="e2883bb9ce7c08ff06a610d32" type="hidden">
<input name="id" value="09a5a74f10" type="hidden">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="MERGE1" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="MERGE2" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="MERGE0" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="" type="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group last">
<input id="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" data-enabled="enabled" value="SIGN UP" type="submit">
</div><br>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="welcome" class="welcome">
<div class="container">
<h1 class="hdng">You've Come to the Right Place</h1>
<p>Allow our knowledgable experts walk you through the 5 stage process to get you to a better place with your Students Payments. </p>
<div class="welcome-info">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
<div class="overlay1">
<h2 class="wow fadeInLeft" style="text-align: center; visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;">TESTIMONIALS</h2>

<div class="testi-item">
<div class="box">

<p class="text-center">"I felt so comfortable and understood. The staff are super supportive, and knowledgeable."</p>
</div>
<div class="client-info text-center">
<div class="client-pic text-center">

<img src="images/client1.jpg" alt="client">
</div>

01/18/2016 <span class="company">Katie B.</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="testi-item">
<div class="box">

<p class="text-center">"I am extremely happy about working with Students Counseling. Both my wife and I have our Students s through here."</p>
</div>
<div class="client-info text-center">
<div class="client-pic text-center">

<img src="images/client2.jpg" alt="client">
</div>

11/17/2014 <span class="company">Roger S.</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="testi-item">
<div class="box">

<p class="text-center">" At first, I was very apprehensive about it because I thought "it's too good to be true," but it isn't! They are saving me so much money, time, and headache!"</p>
</div>
<div class="client-info text-center">
<div class="client-pic text-center">

<img src="images/client3.jpg" alt="client">
</div>

02/09/2015 <span class="company">Remy J.</span>
</div>
</div><hr>
<div id="click2call">
<div style="visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;" class="download-cta wow zoomInUp"><a href="tel:1-888-668-8109" style="text-align: center; color:#d34a4a;" class="callheader"><h3 style="font-size: 30px;"><b>(888) 668-8109</b> </h3></a><br> <a href="tel:1-888-668-8109" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg" style="height: 70px; font-size: 30px;">CLICK TO CALL</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="feature">
<div class="banner-bottom">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div style="visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center feature-title wow fadeInUp">

<h2>What are the Benefits to Consolidation &amp; The New Federal Programs?</h2>
<p>Borrowing to pay for college is the easy part. Repaying the debt is much harder. To know which options are best for you, your career prospects and your budget, it helps to have access to an expert who can guide you through the complexity of the various programs, explain your options under each, and take into account the context of your financial circumstances.</p><br><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-feat">
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">

<div class="feature-img">
<img src="images/grad.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 40rem; height: auto; padding-top: 11rem; visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;" class="img-responsive wow fadeInLeft">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">

<div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
<div class="inner">
<h4>Consolidation Information</h4>
<p>Consolidation programs exist for both federal Students s as well as for private Students s. For many people, consolidation will ease the burden of having multiple lenders, with various balances, interest rates, monthly payments, terms etc. By consolidating, the borrower would have only one , with one monthly payment, interest rate, and term. Federal consolidation are also much easier to qualify for, do not require a credit check, and is available to borrowers in default on their s. </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
<div class="inner">
<h4>Teacher / Public Service Programs</h4>
<p>The Teacher Forgiveness program is probably the most beneficial of all the forgiveness plans available as teachers not only qualify for early forgiveness, but principal reduction as well. You may qualify for public service forgiveness if you work full-time in a public service job. After making 120 payments under certain repayment plans while working full time in a public service position, the balance of your Federal Students would be completely forgiven</p><br><br>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
<div class="inner">
<h4>Income-Based Programs</h4>
<p>William D. Ford Federal Direct Program also known as the Obama Students Forgiveness program, where every consolidated under an income-based program has forgiveness attached at the end of the term. At the end of your consolidated s term, any unpaid balance &amp; interest will be forgiven by the Department of Education.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
<div class="inner">
<h4>Extended-Graduated Plans</h4>
<p>Your payments start out low and then increase every two years. Repayment under this plan may provide lower initial monthly payments, although the total interest paid may be greater when compared to plans with similar terms with fixed payments. This plan may be beneficial if your income is low now but is likely to steadily increase.
</p><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div style="visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;" class="work wow slideInLeft">
<div class="col-md-8 work-grids work-img">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 work-grids">
<h3>Customer Online Portal</h3>
<p>You can rest assured knowing you're in good hands because after your assessment is done your information can only be retrieved through the SSL certification on our website with your own online portal.</p>
<ul>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="#">Access Online 24/7</a></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="#">Privacy from Your own Home</a></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="#">256 bit Encryption Security</a></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="#">Safely Upload Necessary Documents</a></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="#">Up to date Information</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

...

Edit : can't upload the whole file, you'll need to do it by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think you can upload everything after the `...`?

Comment: Also the CSS styles aren't showing up? It looks as if firebug changed some of the CSS styles?

Comment: @user3233623 : no i can't, i hit the answer size limit :)
I only copied the HTML source, you can get CSS sources (as they are multiple one) and computed CSS via firebug "CSS" tab

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you

Comment: this may be a long shot, but do you think you can work your fire bug magic and upload all the code to a file in this repository? It would be one giant step for man kind :D ? https://github.com/tonycrencren/firebug

Comment: for the record, I downloaded firebug, the only thing is it seems to me it's still tons of guess work as to what to actually inspect and copy and paste etc. They need to come out with a mod that lets you select an entire page's code, even if it has frames!

Comment: For the HTML part, you dreams are already became true, as described in the answer. I agree about the CSS and javascript parts, it would have be nice to "consolidate" them in one file.

Comment: Do you think we could make that happen using github?

Answer (score 1):

The frameset at student**s**counseling.org just loads the content of:

`studentcounseling.org` (note singular).

Comment: Hey. What do you mean?

Comment: If you go to studentcounseling.org and view source, you will see it, instead of the frameset you get at studentScounseling.org.

Comment: are you saying I can get the whole file this way?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "whole file" but yes you can get the entire source of the index page there.

Comment: I just want to copy all the code serving the domain 'studentscounseling.org'. Thanks to your help, I'm now aware of the fact that 'studentcounseling.org' is the link that hosts most of the code. The only thing is, its raw html without the CSS. I was kind of looking to just do one big copy and paste in one fell swoop.